# LoadStateEventArgs can't loaded

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

guys, I have a problem with my Store App (Windows 8.1), I don't know the motive.

[image: the code can't load]

The LoadStateEventArgs don't load. 
I put the using assembly `using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;` and don't work.

How fix it?

Comment: You should include something

Comment: Have you check the full example of MSDN ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh986965.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NavigationHelper` and `LoadStateEventArgs` aren't defined in any of the assemblies; they're included directly in your project when you add a new item based on the `Basic Page` template:

[image: New item based on Basic Page template]

Once you do that, a couple of file are added to the `Common` folder:

[image: NavigationHelper.cs in Common folder]

Among them is also `NavigationHelper.cs` which contains both missing classes. Their namespace matches the folder (`App1.Common` in my case).