# What should we use instead of LoadStateEventArgs for Windows 10 Universal App?

Tags: c#, windows, uwp

[The type or namespace name 'LoadStateEventArgs' could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32877811/the-type-or-namespace-name-loadstateeventargs-could-not-be-found)

In that post answer is not clearly. How to pass my data another page?

[LoadStateEventArgs can't loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27651752/loadstateeventargs-cant-loaded)

In that post solution is not valid for Windows 10 Universal App.

Answer (score 1):

Pass them as an argument of [Page.OnNavigatedFrom()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.controls.page.onnavigatedfrom%28VS.95%29.aspx) and receive them as parameters of [Page.OnNavigatedTo()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227508). A good example of this is how data is passed between the MainPage and DetailPage in [Template10](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10)